# JSON Parse splice issue

Tags: javascript

I can't seem to work out why splice isn't working correctly in this instance.

I have read countless stack overflow examples of splice and I can't seem to see an issue.

This code should basically remove index 14, from the first item(and only) in the JSON array.

```
var product_variations = JSON.parse('[{"0":"","1":"","2":"","3":"0.0000","4":"","5":"0.00","6":"0.00","7":"1.00","8":"0","9":"false","10":"false","11":[],"12":"","13":"","14":"Red","15":"Small"}]');

product_variations[0].splice(14, 1);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It does not work because `splice` is a method available on arrays, not on objects.

And this is an object:

```
{"0":"","1":"","2":"","3":"0.0000","4":"","5":"0.00","6":"0.00","7":"1.00","8":"0","9":"false","10":"false","11":[],"12":"","13":"","14":"Red","15":"Small"}
```

Actually you get an error like:

> TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating 'product_variations[0].splice(14, 1)')

You can use `delete` instead or convert it to an array:

```
delete product_variations[0]["14"]
```

To convert it to an array you could try:

```
function objectToArray(p){
    var keys = Object.keys(p);
    keys.sort(function(a, b) {
        return a - b;
    });

    var arr = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        arr.push(p[keys[i]]);
    }
    return arr;
}

var product_variations = JSON.parse('[{"0":"","1":"","2":"","3":"0.0000","4":"","5":"0.00","6":"0.00","7":"1.00","8":"0","9":"false","10":"false","11":[],"12":"","13":"","14":"Red","15":"Small"}]');

var arr = objectToArray(product_variations[0]);

arr.splice(14, 1);
```

Comment: Would there be an easy way to shift the object indexes back 1, after the 14? In the example I posted there was only 15 after the 14, but in the actual implementation there are many more.

Comment: @jdawg No, not an easy way. I recommend you to convert the whole object to an array, I can add an example if you want.

Comment: Sure an example would be great.

Comment: @jdawg I've added an example.

Answer (score 3):

Use the "delete" keyword in Javascript.

```
delete myArray["lastname"];
```

As mentioned, it does not work because your object is just a list and what you are using is a object (assoc array)

**.splice**

> The splice() method adds/removes items to/from an array, and returns the removed item(s).
>
> Note: This method changes the original **array**.

**delete**

> The delete operator removes a property from an **object**.

So your code should look like

```
delete product_variations[0]["14"]
```

Remember that the 14 number is a string, not a number, as you have written in your code, since that's the name of the element in your array.

Nevertheless, I highly recommend you, after having seen the code you are managing, to switch that to a list, since the keywords are only like the indices of a normal list (with the exception that they start in 1)

Comment: *"Remember that the 14 number is a string, not a number"* All JavaScript keys are converted to string so `14` and `"14"` are seen as identical.

Comment: @LyeFish ah, I didn't know you could do that